# SystemOut.log file string search, Count and Alert via email when count reaches 10

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, tail

I want to monitor SystemOut.log file using tail -f so I tried and held up with tail -f which is not allowing me to do other operations simultaneously. I might have missed few things, which you guys can help me out. I searched but couldn't get an answer.

QUESTION:Every 5 mins I going to trigger the below script to count 'string' occurrences using tail -f with grep and writing it to a file called msg.txt (its solaris so -q didn't work in grep any recommendations here welcome)

Simultaneously, Counting the string occurrences and checking if the count reaches 10 then triggering an email with the msg.txt file. Finally, stopping the while and I don't want it to continue once it reaches its count value 10. This program will be triggered every 5 minutes once, I just want to make sure its terminated when the count reaches 10. How would I stop this script if count doesn't reach 10 with in the 5 minutes, because it will be triggered again?

```
while true ; do

  tail -f SystemOut.log | grep "string" > msg.txt # SystemOut.log for currently running process 

  Count = Count + 1 

  if test $Count == 10

    mail -s "Email Subject" abc@abc.com < msg.txt 

    break

  fi  

done
```

Rewriting the same bit differently, but having issue with grep -c shouts for file can't be opened I don't know whats causing the issue. Any help much appreciated.

while true;

do

COUNT_1= grep -c "search string" LOG_FILE

sleep 300
COUNT_2= grep -c "search string" LOG_FILE
COUNT= [[ $COUNT_2-$COUNT_1]]

if [[ $COUNT > 10 ]]
then
echo $COUNT
fi

done

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this might work:

```
grep 'string' SystemOut.log > msg.txt

count=`wc -l msg.txt`

if [[ $count == "10" ]]; 
  mail -s "Email Subject" abc@abc.com < msg.txt   
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried your code, what happens with your code is grep command keeps on writing the search string line into msg.txt without stopping so the count and if condition below are never reached. The SystemOut.log file which I'm using is going to be a log file written with 100's of lines every second. So I thought tail the log and count it and check for the condition whether the count reached maximum if so then email otherwise continue the count.